# Merging of 2 sets of intervals

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I have a union method setup to combine 2 sets of ordered intervals:

```
(define (union set1 set2)
  (cond [(empty? set1) set2]
        [(empty? set2) set1]
        [(< (caar set1) (caar set2)) (cons (car set1) (union (cdr set1)
                                                             set2))]
        [else (cons (car set2) (union set1
                                      (cdr set2)))]))
```

Given 2 lists  `'((1 3) (5 10) (19 29))` and `'((2 4) (17 25) (30 49))` they produce

`'((1 3) (2 4) (5 10) (17 25) (19 29) (30 49))` with the code above.

But with the above implementation the overlapping intervals aren't being handled correctly. I am needing to merge the overlapping intervals to produce `'((1 3) (2 4) (5 10) (17 29) (30 49))`.  How could I go about handling these interval merges so that there are no overlaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're working with half-open intervals `[from upto)`, Racket provides an [`interval-map`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/data/interval-map.html) module:

> An interval-map is a mutable data structure that maps half-open intervals of exact integers to values. An interval-map is queried at a discrete point, and the result of the query is the value mapped to the interval containing the point.

The provided examples:

```
> (define r (make-interval-map))
> (interval-map-set! r 1 5 'apple)
> (interval-map-set! r 6 10 'pear)
> (interval-map-set! r 3 7 'banana)
> (dict-map r list)
'(((1 . 3) apple) ((3 . 7) banana) ((7 . 10) pear))
```

Using your example inputs `'((1 3) (5 10) (19 29))` and `'((2 4) (17 25) (30 49))`:

```
#lang racket/base
(require data/interval-map
         racket/list
         racket/match
         racket/dict)

(define im (make-interval-map))

;; Add your first set
(for ([x '((1 3) (5 10) (19 29))])
  (interval-map-set! im (first x) (second x) #f))

;; Add your second set
(for ([x '((2 4) (17 25) (30 49))])
  (interval-map-set! im (first x) (second x) #f))

;; The result
(map car (dict-map im list))
;; => '((1 . 2) (2 . 4) (5 . 10) (17 . 25) (25 . 29) (30 . 49))
```